# Which is the fastest method to add values with Jquery in HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, optimization

With pure HTML and then adding the value via jquery:

```
  <div id="leftAxis">
    <div class="leftQuadrant">
      <div id="oneval" class="insideQuadrant"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="leftQuadrant">
      <div id="twoVal" class="insideQuadrant"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="leftQuadrant">
      <div id="threeVal" class="insideQuadrant"></div>
    </div>
  </div>


    fillLeftAxis: function() {
        var data = ['one', 'two', 'three'],
            IdHtml = ['#oneVal', '#twoVal', '#threeVal'];

        for(var i=0; i<IdHtml.length; i++) {
            $(IdHtml[i]).html(data[i]);
        }
    };
```

Or directly construct the HTML elements with the value in it and append it later to the container with jquery:

```
  <div id="leftAxis">
  </div>

fillLeftAxis: function() {
    var data = ['one', 'two', 'three'],
        html = '';

    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        html += '<div class="leftQuadrant"><div id="' + data[i] + 'Val" class="insideQuadrant">' + data[i] + '</div></div>';
    }

    $('#leftAxis').html(html);
};
```

Comment: If you really need some fast code, drop jQuery.

Comment: if you only adding text use `jQuery.text()`. But i can only agree with the previous post: If you want it fast do native JS. jQuery has lots of overhead. `$(IdHtml[i]).html(data[i])` will create an array like structure with the one entry, itterate over the element and perform the `html` function.

Comment: If you're using the second method (build a bulk of html) then making a *single* jquery call, the "overhead" will be extremely minimal.  Even if you use the first method, the "overhead" of using `$(id).html()` compared with native will also be entirely minimal (as the vastly larger overhead will be with redrawing).  So, while a general sweeping statement of 'jquery has overheads' is generally correct, the actual overhead in *this* scenario isn't worth not using jquery.  So depends on your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select all elements with class `"insideQuadrant"` instead of using jQuery, that is an external library with a lot of methods that you probably do not need all of them in your script (or project).

Than you can iterate over all the aray of `elements` with [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Code:

```js
(function () {
  var data = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

  document
    .querySelectorAll('.insideQuadrant')
    .forEach(function (element, index) {
      element.textContent = data[index];
    });
})();
```

```html
<div id="leftAxis">
  <div class="leftQuadrant">
    <div class="insideQuadrant"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="leftQuadrant">
    <div class="insideQuadrant"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="leftQuadrant">
    <div class="insideQuadrant"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Notice**: that for this case there is no need to use element id attributes because that will require more querys to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

the second way.

the first way causes Dom Tree refreshing each loop, and that causes heavy performance expending. not suggested.

see more details about Dom rending and UI Thread in browsers.